# Is it possible to get Location Service's "Significant Locations" using CLLocationManager in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cllocationmanager

I'm looking to get locations that are already significant to a user without having to rebuild a list of their frequent locations. I noticed that in the phone's settings there's "Significant Locations" in

> Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Significant
>   Locations

I'm not sure if it's accessible using Swift. Is it possible to get these locations for use in my app?

Comment: That list isn't exposed by any API.  Take a look at `CLVisit`

Comment: So since it's not exposed by any API I need to re-build a list of significant locations using CLVisit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the places a user has been before your app was installed. You can only get the locations that the user has been to after your app is installed. To do that use a `CLLocationManager` with "Visits" by calling [`-startMonitoringVisits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1618692-startmonitoringvisits) and waiting until the user stops somewhere. You'll need to get explicit authorization from the user to receive Visits information.

Documentation: [Using the Visits Location Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service)

**Note:** The "Significant Locations" in the Settings app is different from Core Location's Significant Location Change Monitoring